# Add class to an element based on placement with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul>
 <li>First</li>
 <li>Second</li>
 <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to add a class to the second `li` listed above with jQuery, without a prexisting class or id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you would go like

```
$('ul li:eq(1)').addClass('yourclassname');
```

Since the selector is zero-based, `1` represents the second node.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: `$(...).eq(1).` would be faster, according to the jQuery docs

Comment: You could also do `ul li:nth-of-type(1)` or `ul li:nth-child(1)` for pure CSS3

Comment: @Alnitak: it would be even faster to go like `$('ul').find('li').slice(1,2)`, but the question was not about performance so I stick with the shortest version here.

Comment: @josh.trow `nth-child` is 1 based, not 0 based.